# NOT NULL constraint failed: UserWithItem.fullName (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL) in Android Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've got a problem when trying to save my data class to room database I've created:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: UserWithItem.fullName (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:879)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
        at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insertAndReturnId(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:114)
        at com.lswarss.ing_project.db.UserWithItemDao_Impl$3.call(UserWithItemDao_Impl.java:154)
        at com.lswarss.ing_project.db.UserWithItemDao_Impl$3.call(UserWithItemDao_Impl.java:149)
        at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:54)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run(TransactionExecutor.java:45)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Parcelize
data class UserWithItem(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val userWithItemId : Int? = null,
    @Embedded val user: UserItem,
    @Embedded(prefix = "post_")val post: PostItem) : Parcelable
```

Comment: Data class you've shown contains two embedded fields. Each of them contains its own fields. Sqlite table for this class holds all fields of your UserItem and PostItem classes. So when you save your data (UserWithItem) actually you inserted a lot of fields, not 3. Message error is about one of them (fullName), it can't be Null. It seemed that while inserting you don't fill the field "user", that produces error

Comment: @sergiytikhonov you are genius man! Right now I know what's wrong, thank you very much for the tip I appreciate that